# Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: reactjs

I have a function which calculates the date from a unix timestamp

```
_getTime(time) {
var dateTime = new Date(time*1000);

console.log(dateTime);
return dateTime

  },
```

The function is used in this

```
render: function() {
    return (    
       {this.state.daily.map(day => {
          return (
             <div key={day.time} className="key col-md-12">
               <div className="col-md-3">{this._getTime(day.time)}</div>
             </div>
          );
    );
},
```

This returns `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Thu Oct 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of`App`.`

I am aware of there questions with the same error message, but I can't seem to figure out a solution for my problem.

Comment: You're trying to render a date, try converting it to a string first using .toString() inside the div

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it worked

Comment: I just had this error. why need toString()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain javascript:

```
_getTime(time) {
    var dateTime = new Date(time*1000).toString();    
    console.log(dateTime);
    return dateTime    
 },
```

Using moment.js

```
_getTime(time) {
    var dateTime = moment(time*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');    
    console.log(dateTime);
    return dateTime    
 },
```

Comment: I just had this error. why need toString()? What dose React treat Date as?